# When can a 'polynomial' have an infinite number of zeroes

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

As indicated in the title the intended meaning of 'polynomial' here is slightly nonstandard, and if there is a better word please feel free to edit. For our purposes:

> A polynomial $\mathfrak{p}$ will be a member of some integral monoid ring $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{M})$, so for each $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{M})$ there is some $\alpha\in \mathbf{On}$, the class of ordinals, and a unique pair of sequences $\{z_i\}_{i<\alpha}\subset\mathbb{Z}$ and $\{m_i\}_{i<\alpha}\subset\mathbb{M}$ (an additive monoid) such that $$\mathfrak{p}=\sum_{i<\alpha}z_iT^{m_i}.$$

Addition and multiplication behave as expected in usual polynomial multiplication with $T$ as an arbitrary indeterminate, where the addition in $\mathbb{M}$ may or may not be commutative. Further, $\alpha$ may be finite or transfinite, and in the latter case I would like to allow a transfinite number of nonzero terms in the polynomial. I believe this is equivalent to looking at Hahn series or a slight generalization of them if we require that $\mathbb{M}$ be an ordered monoid, however I am only interested in an algebraic property of $\mathfrak{p}$ in general so I cast the question in terms of more algebraic objects.

My question is:

> Under what general conditions will $\mathfrak{p}$ have a unique* transfinite prime factorization in $\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{M})$, in the sense that there exists a sequence $\{\mathfrak{p}_i\}_{i<\lambda}\subset\mathbb{Z}(T^\mathbb{M})$ for $\lambda\geq\omega$ such that $\forall i\big(\mathfrak{p}_i\neq1\big)$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\Pi_{i<\lambda}\mathfrak{p}_i$, while no other sequence produces $\mathfrak{p}$ as its product?
>
> *possibly with stipulations about the uniqueness of the factorization

If this question is perhaps too general, I would still be very much  interested in the special case where $\mathbb{M}$ is discretely ordered, or the addition in $\mathbb{M}$ is commutative, or we restrict $\alpha$ to be countable or $\omega$. This came up during some research I'm doing pertaining to non-Archimedean ordered rings, which can be viewed as integral monoid algebras with a judicious choice of discretely ordered monoid and allowed 'polynomial' length, and in this setting polynomial factorization corresponds to factorization of elements in the ring. It seems like all the monoids I'm looking at produce unique finite factorizations for $\alpha<\omega$, but it feels like there should be some simple generalizations which will produce integral monoid algebras with the above property.

Comment: How do you define the product if infinite sequences are allowed? Won't you have to deal with infinite sums of integers?

Comment: @nombre I actually answered this question with a paper I wrote recently; in short no, because we can allow 'sums' with infinitely decreasing exponent sequences which produce telescoping sums under multiplicative composition, and all but the well-behaved terms cancel out.  The preprint will be available on the arxiv this tuesday; I'll type up an answer regarding these developments after some early christmas festivities this evening.

Comment: Interesting, I'll come back then!

Comment: What does $O_n$ stand for?

Comment: @GerryMyerson The class of ordinals.

Comment: There are some things in your paper that would deserve to be rewritten (mostly for reader-friendlyness and concision sakes but also because of some rather minor mistakes). If you like, I can detail more when I have some time later. 
Your proof of the validity algorithm seems alright however and I think this asks interesting algebraic questions about the ring.

Comment: @nombre That would be much appreciated -- I'm currently fleshing out a brief paper on the connection between naked polynomials and Hahn series fields as you suggested, and it is pretty interesting IMO.  I will update this post with a link to it when it is finished, probably some time later this weekend/next week.

Comment: I'll write something down then. Maybe it would be better to talk about that on the chat or via email (if you are okay with that).

Comment: @nombre Email would be excellent -- one of my professors also suggested that this construction reminded him of Hahn series fields, so I am typing up the short latex mainly to clarify the matter for interested parties.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ord}{Ord}$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Noo}{No}$It seems to me that you are redefining existing notions: this is exactly the Hahn series structure except the ordered group is now the positive part of a discretely ordered group, while $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ is the Grothendieck group (/ring) associated to the monoïd (/semi-ring) structure of $\Ord$, and $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}$ is its fraction field.

I don't think the latter's real closure can be densely embedded in $\Noo$ for it contains no element strictly between $\mathbb{N}$ and $X^{\frac{1}{\mathbb{N}+1}}$.

I understand why you might want to see $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}$ as "versions" of integers and rationnal numbers, but do they really share their properties to the extent that such vocabulary and notations would be relevant?

Apart form that, a proof that those rings have a kind of euclidean division (mind that the term "euclidean domain" is reserved for domains with an euclidean function) would be very nice indeed. Do you have someone checking your proof?

---

**A note on how to add cuts to ordered fields:**

Given an ordered field $F$, and a *cut* $(L,R)$ in it, that is subsets (or subclasses here) with $L < R$, $F = L \cup R$ and $L/R$ have no maximum/minimum, there is a canonical way to add it to $F$ and thus obtain a simple extension denoted $F(L \ | \ R)$ henceforth.

Let's say that $(L,R)$ is *of algebraic type* if there is some polynomial $P \in F[X]$ such that there is *neigborhood of the cut*, that is, a convex subset $C$ of $F$ intersecting $L$ and $R$ if they are not empty, such that $P$ is strictly negative on $C \cap L$ and strictly positive on $C \cap R$.

Otherwise, say that $(L,R)$ is *of transcendantal type*.

Since $F$ can be embedded in a real closure, polynomials in $F[X]$ have less sign shifts than their degree, and this implies that:

$(i)$: If $(L,R)$ is of transcendental type, then for each polynomial $P \in F[X]$, there is a neighborhood $C$ of $(L,R)$ such that $P$ has constant sign on $C$. $P$ is defined to be strictly positive in $F[X]$ if this sign is strictly positive. This defines a positive cone on $F[X]$ that is naturally extended to $F(L \ |  \ R):= F(X)$, and in the resulting field, $L < X < R$.

$(ii)$: If $(L,R)$ is of algebraic type, chose $P$ with minimal degree satisfying the conditions of the definition. $P$ is then irreducible for having constant sign on neighborhoods is stable by product.
For $S = PQ + T \in F[X] / (P)$ with $\deg(T) < \deg(P)$, we find a neighborhood $C$ of $(L,R)$ such that $T$ has constant sign on $C$ and define this as the sign of $S$.
To see that this defines a positive cone on $F[X] /(P)$, the non trivial part is to see that if $S > 0$ then $S^2 > 0$. Towards this, write $T^2 = PQ_1+ R_1$ with $\deg(R_1) < \deg(P)$, note that $\deg(Q_1)  = 2\deg(T) - \deg(P)< \deg(P)$, so $Q_1$ has constant sign on a neighborhood $C_1$ of $(L,R)$ and by choosing a small enough one we get that $T,R_1$ have constant sign as well. Since $R_1 = T^2 - PQ_1$ is strictly positive on either $L$ or $R$, the constant sign is $1$ so $S^2 > 0$.
In the resulting ordered field $F( L \  | \ R):= F[X] / (P)$, $L < X + (P) < R$ (and  of course $X + (P)$ is a root of $P$).

There is an equivalent formulation with pseudo-Cauchy sequences but it only works with cuts that are sufficiently spaced so that valuation theoretic arguments can apply.
With this one as with the valued field version, there is a subtlety in the algebraic type version in that if $F(a)$ is a proper simple ordered field extension of $F$ and $(L,R)$ denotes the cut in $F$ defined by $a$, that is $L = F \cap ]-\infty;a[$ and $R := F \cap ]a;+\infty[$, then $a$ may not be algebraic over $F$ even if $(L_a,R_a)$ has algebraic type.

When the cut is "Dedekind" in the sense that $\{r-l \ | \ (l,r) \in L \times R\}$ is coinitial in $F^{>0}$, the resulting ordered field $F(L \ | \ R)$ is a dense extension, and adding the cut is similar to adding a Cauchy sequence. It is possible to add all such cuts at once and define Dedekind-like operations on the set of Dedekind cuts in $F$. (note that those cuts can have algebraic or transcendent type) You then get a dense extension without proper dense extensions (=maximal dense extension), which is a nice generalization of completeness for ordered fields. It is also possible to add all Cauchy sequences at once or even to take a uniform completion of the field to get the same result.

Adding all agebraic type cuts inductively gives a real closure. In fact, an ordered field is real closed iff it has no algebraic type cut.

Adding all cuts inducitvely (unlike adding enough pseudo-limits) is impossible  for an ordered field $F'$ always has $(F',\varnothing)$ as a cut (and as soon as $F'$ is non-archimedean, it has the cut defined by $\mathbb{N}$). I suppose it is possible under global choice to add all set-sized cuts, and get Field which may be saturated and may under global choice be isomorphic to $\Noo$, but I guess this is a bit artificial for your taste.

---

So this works because one can evaluate polynomials in $F[X]$ at points of $F$.

The problem is that it is hard to see how to evaluate elements such as $X^{\omega}$ in $R:=\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}[X^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}]$ (I think the notation $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}((X^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}))$, which speaks for itself when one knows Hahn series, should be prefered here), and that there is no clear way, even with an euclidean-like function, of specifying a condition for an element in the polynomial ring $R[\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+]$ of polynomials with indeterminates in the monoïd $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+$ and coefficients in $R$, so that given an irreducible element $a$ of $R[\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+]$, the elements in $R[\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+]$ with less degree cannot for instance change signs over one cut. (The problem here being that the degree takes values in $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+$ which is not well-ordered.)

---

You could try to embed $R$ in a nice way in $\Noo$, find out the cut defined by $a$ in $\Noo$, intersect it with $R$ (fortunately, the maps $0 <x \mapsto \exp(a\log(x))$ and their sums belong to an o-minimal structure so they may not shift signs too often either) and then add it to $R$.

But:

-This makes the definition extrinsic and a priori very dependant on the chosen embedding.

-I am not sure there is a "canonical" embedding of $R$ into $\Noo$.
We might want to embed it as an initial subring in the sense the work of Ehrlich, since $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}$ is a truncature-closed subfield of $\mathbb{Q}((\omega^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}}))$, so $R$ is a truncature-closed subring of $\mathbb{Q}((x^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}))$ (with lexicographic order on $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+$ with empasis on second coordinate). Then you would need to find a way to see $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty} \times \mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+$ as an ititial submonoïd of $\Noo$ which is not that obvious. (maybe $(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto \beta + sign(\alpha)\log(\omega^{-|\alpha|})$ where $sign(\alpha) \in \{-1;0;1\}$ works?). More importantly, one could ask whether your choice of embedding is natural or interesting.

-Given an embedding, it is not sure that for instance the cuts defined by $a: = Z^{\omega}-\omega$ and $b: = Z^{\omega+1} - \omega$ will differ. This would undermine the relevance of the phrasing "adding a $\omega$-th root of $\omega$". If the cut is added intrinsically using the process to add cuts, then either this process has to be generalized to those special polynomials (which I doubt is possible in general), or the image of $X$ in the extension will lack a real algebraic caracterisation as a $\omega$-th root of $\omega$ (in the case of $Z^{\omega} - \omega$).

Finally, about the intuition of non density of the field obtained by adding $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+$-th roots of elements of $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}$, this is still vague but I imagine the value group of the resulting field (which is the same as that of any dense extension) would be $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}$ which is not isomorphic to $\Noo$.

Comment: Yes, two of the professors at my college have been working with me over the past year or so on this, and one of them is planning on publishing subsequent research with me on the number theoretic structure of $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$.  They both kindly offered to let me have sole authorship as this is my first real research endeavor, and they felt I had done the majority of the work.  (cont.)

Comment: This is distinct from a Hahn series structure in exactly the same way a usual polynomial ring is distinct from a power series ring; it can be identified through an embedding, but it has a nice and robust structure of its own that is easier to understand from a ring theoretic standpoint.  The recursion I define in my paper is a Euclidean function on $\mathbb{Q}[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]$.  $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$ and $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ actually are proper class sized nonstandard models of the integers and rationals, with identical first order theories.

Comment: Also, note that the quotient ring of my structure by the irreducible polynomial $X^{\omega+1}-\omega$ has an element strictly where you are concerned about. Additionally I misspoke above; the recursion itself is not an Euclidean function, it is the Euclidean division on the ring, but it shows that the standard notion of a degree still is an Euclidean function.

Comment: Further, note that the explicit difference between this and the Hahn series ring $\mathbb{Q}_\infty[[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]]$ is exactly the requirement that all subsets of the support (all subsets of the exponents in $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$) must have a maximal element, which reverse well-orders them and is exactly what allows for the ordering and recursive euclidean structure on the ring.  This distinction is important in my opinion.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean about the distinction. Are you familiar with Hahn series fields and valuation theory? I think this field might interest and help you.

Comment: I understand what the Euclidean-like function you use is, it just isn't an euclidean function in the standard sense because those are assumed to be natural number valued while yours takes values in $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$. Can you write $\omega$ as a sum of four squares in $\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}$? As for the last comment, do you mean $X^{\omega+1} - X$ (or $\omega^{\omega+1} - \omega$ as I framed it)? How could the quotient ring be ordered when those are reducible?

Comment: Yes, I have Allings book where he builds the Surreals as Hahn series with real number coefficients and Surreal exponents.  And no, I meant $X^{\omega+1}-\omega$, the function which maps $0$ to $-\omega$ and $\omega+1$ to $1$. The Euclidean function taking on values in $\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+$ is necessary for Surreal roots like $\sqrt[\omega]{\omega+1}$, etc. (reposted to edit) This paper is also currently under review for publication if you would like to wait for a peer review before digging in.

Comment: I do see your point about writing $\omega$ as a sum of four primes, as this is impossible in $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$ -- the first order theories are apparently different, but prime factorization is the main property I needed to pull through which the Omnific integers fail to have.

Comment: Ooh okay, my bad I thought you were working on $\mathbb{Q}[X^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}]$. So do you mean that if $R$ denotes $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty}[X^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}]$, then $R[T^{\mathbb{Z}_{\infty}^+}]$ can be quotiented by maximal ideals in a way that yields canonically ordered fields? How so? (note that the implication Euclidean domain ==> factorial domain is only true for real euclidean domains)

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{Q}_\infty[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]$ we can quotient out by the maximal ideals generated by irreducible polynomials to canonically produce ordered field extensions.  I lay out the process for doing this in my paper, but it is essentially just the standard construction (I explicitly show that ideals generated by irreducible polynomials are still maximal, so their quotients are indeed fields).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $R[T^{\mathbb{Z}^+_\infty}]$, but by $\mathbb{Q}_\infty[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+}]$ I mean the set of all functions from $\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+$ to $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ such that all subsets of the support must have a maximal element, as defined above.  This is not a Hahn series ring (an additional $2^{nd}$ order requirement is imposed), which may be leading to your confusion.

Comment: I'll try to be more clear: this to me is exactly a Hahn series field except the value group is just a monoïd and well-ordered supports are replaced with reversed well-ordered ones. And there is no problem with obtaining a field by quotienting by a maximal ideal in general comutative algebra, what's puzzling here is the fact that the field is ordered. The standard proof of how one can add a root of a polynomial to an ordered ring uses the fact that polynomials can be evaluated in said ring, while here, it is unclear how one would evaluate $Z^{\omega+1} - \omega$ in $R$ (except at monomials).

Comment: I agree that this is a bit of a subtle issue, and I've been exploring options for explicitly showing how it is ordered (see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2494813/ordered-field-extension).  I suspect that I may, at least initially, have to identify the roots I'm adding with roots I already know exist in the surreals to define how I order them in the extension.  I would like to avoid 'cheating' like this, as the whole point is to build back out the surreals and better understand their constituent structural pieces, but it should work I believe.

Comment: This might work but the resulting field will most likely fail to be dense, since its value group will likely be $\mathbb{Q}_{\infty} \neq \Noo$. I'll post a comment on how to try to order the quotient fields tonight.

Comment: If it still fails to be dense I will eat my shirt; the density of the surreals never ceases to amaze me.  Thank you for your interest and assistance, and if you're successful and would like to be part of the paper please send me an email. The next step in this process was going to be looking at the class of all pseudo-convergent sequences over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\infty$ mod their pseudo-limits to form the surreals, but perhaps this is just another step required to increase density.

Comment: I also defined an ordering on the quotient ring in my paper, but this was by intuition and I'm not sure it works on further consideration.  Essentially, once we have a maximal ideal $\mathcal{I}$ we want to quotient by, the relation we want to use is a congruence relation so we can pull all the algebraic operations directly through up to equivalence class, and we should then also be able to pull the ordering defined on the ring through up to equivalence class.  This is laid out more explicitly in the paper.

Comment: I see that your paper defines the algebraic structure on quotient (but isn't this just the general definition of quotient?), but matters regarding order seem to be eluded. As you can guess, this topic is of great interest for me as well (I can even say you and I share some mathematical similarities), and I would gladly keep in touch with you if you or I have a question for each other, but I will probably lack time to engage in writing an article or this type of stuff. Still I'm interested. I will edit my answer to talk about adding cuts to an ordered field.

Comment: Much appreciated! Same to you, and I will read your edit more carefully when this hectic week has ended.

Comment: @AlecRhea: Yes, take your time. In the meantime I'll read your papers to see where you are going with this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a suitable answer to this question while questing for a new construction of the surreal numbers. The following is the math story of how I found the answer, which may be skipped in favor of the answer itself below the fold if you prefer.

In my first paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08908), I had extended the ordinals to a proper class sized discretely ordered ring which I called  $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$ (the Surintegers) and which admit prime factorization, then formed a densely ordered proper class sized field of fractions for this ring called the Surrational numbers $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$.

I expected to find $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ dense in the Surreals because their construction from $O_n$ is so similar to the construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\omega$, but I was incorrect.  They are dense in the pieces of the Surreal line where they exist, for instance around $0$ or $\pm\omega^\alpha$ for any $\alpha$, however around higher roots of prime infinities in $\mathbb{Z}_\infty$ they are not defined -- for example around $\sqrt[3]{\omega}$, $\sqrt[4]{\omega}$, $\sqrt[\omega]{\omega_1}$, etc.

To solve this problem, I needed a Gaois theory of $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$ which allowed me to form polynomials with infinite exponents and coefficients like $X^\omega-\omega_1$, which ended up giving rise to the following constructions. I believe that the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$, denoted $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_\infty$ and formed as the final culmination of the following construction over $\mathbb{Q}_\infty$, is dense in all parts of the Surreal line and will allow a satisfying 'closure' into the Surreals.

---

The following construction is an appropriate notion of an 'infinite polynomial ring' (it is an ordered Euclidean domain), and quotient rings over this structure will contain infinite unique prime factorizations. This is almost verbatim from an upcoming paper I've written; a preprint is available here https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00662.

> Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an ordered field, and let ${\mathbb{G}^+}$ be the nonnegative part of a discretely ordered group. We define $\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ to be $\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{G}^+}_{\subseteq max}$, the ordered group algebra whose elements are functions $f:{\mathbb{G}^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}$ such that all subsets $\mathbb{A}\subseteq supp(f)\subseteq\mathbb{G}^+$ have a maximal element, together with the standard algebraic structure and a total ordering structure. More precisely, we define $$\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]=\{f\in\mathbb{F}^{\mathbb{G}^+}:\mathbb{A}\subset supp(f)\implies\exists x\in\mathbb{A}\forall y\in\mathbb{A}\big[y\leq x\big]\}.$$ For $p\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ we will write $p=(p_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}}=(p_0,\dots)$, where $p_\alpha$ is the image of $\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}$ under $p$; we denote by $supp(p)\subseteq{\mathbb{G}^+}$ the set of elements whose image is nonzero. Let $q\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ as well with $q=(q_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}}$. The addition $\hat+:\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\times\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ is given by $$p\hat+q=(p_\alpha+q_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}},$$ $$\hat+=\langle p\hat+q:p,q\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rangle.$$ Negation $\hat -:\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ is then given by $$-p=(-p_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}},$$ $$\hat-=\langle-p:p\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rangle.$$ Multiplication $\hat\times:\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\times\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rightarrow\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ is then defined coordinate-wise by $$(p\hat\times q)_\gamma=\sum_{\alpha+\beta=\gamma}p_\alpha q_\beta$$ where we have renamed the indices of $q$, yielding $$p\hat\times q=\big((p\hat\times q)_\gamma\big)_{\gamma\in{\mathbb{G}^+},}$$ $$\hat\times=\langle p\hat\times q:p,q\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]\rangle.$$ Finally, the ordering on $\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$, written as $\preceq$, is defined as follows. For all $p,q\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$, let $$_p\uparrow_q=\max\{g\in\mathbb{G}^+:p(g)\neq q(g)\},$$ so $_p\uparrow_q\in\mathbb{G}^+$ is the last coordinate at which $p$ and $q$ differ -- this is well defined since $\{g\in\mathbb{G}^+:p(g)\neq q(g)\}\subseteq\big[supp(p)\cup supp(q)\big]$. We then define $$\preceq=\{(p,q):p(_p\uparrow_q)<q(_p\uparrow_q)\vee p=q\},$$ which is essentially a reverse lexicographic ordering on the functions, where the discretely ordered monoid elements serve as the letter positions. The members of $\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ will be called **naked polynomials**, and we will refer to $\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ as a **naked polynomial ring** over $\mathbb{F}$.

If we view a naked polynomial $p=(p_\alpha)_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}}$ as a 'dressed up' polynomial by writing it as $$p=\sum_{\alpha\in{\mathbb{G}^+}}p_\alpha X^\alpha,$$ the above definitions match exactly our intuition for how polynomials should behave. The definitions and notation employed here are to emphasize that the structure underlying the 'exponents' of a polynomial ring is not most correctly described as that of a vector space basis, but rather an indexed collection of discretely ordered positions such that all subsets of filled positions have a maximal element, together with a canonical addition of positions.  Polynomial addition combines elements in identical positions, and multiplication fuses elements from different positions in the classically understood "add the exponents" fashion. Further, $_{\hat0}\uparrow_q$ plays the role of $deg(q)$ for all naked polynomials $q\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$, where $\hat0\in\mathbb{F}[X^{\mathbb{G}^+}]$ is the function with empty support, and the additive identity is $\hat1=(1,0,0,\dots)$.

The notion of a naked polynomial ring is a canonical generalization of a polynomial ring in the sense that a naked polynomial ring is a polynomial ring when the discretely ordered monoid in question is the countable infinity $\omega$ under natural addition, or equivalently the natural numbers (note that supports must be finite in this case). Using $\mathbb{Z}_\lambda^+$ (or all of $\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+$) produces larger non-Archimedean discretely ordered monoids with the necessary property, and consequently a generalized notion of a polynimial ring.

For a proof that the above structure forms an Euclidean domain, feel free to refernce the preprint above.

When I can figure out how to format polynomial long division on here, I will give a few cool examples of how to find the CGD of two of these polynomials (it is just a transfinite version of the usual division recursion). For now, I will use these finished divisions where $\mathbb{G}^+=\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+$ is the positive part of the Surintegers under addition, which properly contains all of the ordinals (think non-negative part of the Grothendieck group of $O_n$): $$(X^2+1)\Big(\sum_{\alpha\in\omega_1}X^{\omega_1-(2+4\alpha)}+X^{\omega_1-(3+4\alpha)}\Big)=\sum_{\alpha\in\omega_1}X^{\omega_1-\alpha},$$$$(X^{\omega^\omega-\omega+3}-X^{\omega^\omega-\omega})\Big(\sum_{\alpha\in\omega}X^{\omega-3(\alpha+1)}\Big)=X^{\omega^\omega}.$$ There are many more cool examples to be found!

EDIT: Here is the Euclidean division on $\mathbb{Q}_\infty[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]$ from my paper, defined by recursion on some set-sized ordinal (see the paper for details):

> $$\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^0=\big({_\beta[\frac{\mathfrak{p}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}{\mathfrak{q}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}]_{\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{p}-\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}}}\big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+},$$ $$\mathfrak{s}^0=\mathfrak{p}\hat-\mathfrak{q}\hat\times\big({_\beta[\frac{\mathfrak{p}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}{\mathfrak{q}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}]_{\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{p}-\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}}}\big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+},$$ $$\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^\alpha=\Big(\sum_{i<\alpha}{_\beta}[\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^i]_{\uparrow^i}\Big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+}+\big({_\beta}[\frac{\mathfrak{s}^{\alpha-1}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}{\mathfrak{q}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}]_{\uparrow^0_{\mathfrak{s}^{\alpha-1}}-\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}}\big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+},\ \text{if}\ \alpha\ \text{is a successor ordinal},$$ $$\mathfrak{s}^\alpha=\mathfrak{s}^{\alpha-1}\hat-\mathfrak{q}\hat\times\big({_\beta[\frac{\mathfrak{s}^{\alpha-1}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}{\mathfrak{q}_{_{\uparrow^0}}}]_{\uparrow^0_{\mathfrak{s}^{\alpha-1}}-\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}}}\big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+},\ \text{if}\ \alpha\ \text{is a successor ordinal},$$ $$\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^{\gamma}=\Big(\sum_{\alpha<\gamma}{_\beta}[\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^\alpha]_{\uparrow^\alpha}\Big)_{\beta\in\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+},\ 0<\gamma\ \text{is a limit ordinal},$$ $$\mathfrak{s}^{\gamma}=\mathfrak{p}\hat-\mathfrak{q}\hat\times\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}^{\gamma},\ 0<\gamma\ \text{is a limit ordinal}.$$ Note that the recursion taking place here only terminates at a successor step if $\uparrow^0_{\mathfrak{s}^\alpha}<\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}$ for some successor ordinal $\alpha$ -- in other words it only terminates if the degree of $\mathfrak{s}^\alpha$ is less than the degree of $\mathfrak{q}$ for some successor $\alpha$, which only happens if $\uparrow^\beta_\mathfrak{p}$ and $\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}$ are comparable for some $\beta$ such that $\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}\leq\uparrow^\beta_\mathfrak{p}$. If $\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}<<\uparrow^\beta_\mathfrak{p}$ for all $\beta$, or if $\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}<<\uparrow^\alpha_\mathfrak{p}$ for all $\alpha<\beta$ and $\uparrow^0_\mathfrak{q}>\uparrow^\beta_\mathfrak{p}$ for some $0<\beta\in O_n$, the recursion terminates at the limit ordinal step $\omega\cdot\beta$.

$\mathfrak{q}\lceil\mathfrak{p}$ is the quotient of $\mathfrak{p}$ by $\mathfrak{q}$, $\mathfrak{s}$ is the remainder, and $\mathfrak{s}=\hat0$ or $deg(\mathfrak{s})<deg(\mathfrak{q})$ always holds. Consequently, the Euclidean function on $\mathbb{Q}_\infty[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]$ is simply the function $deg:\mathbb{Q}_\infty[X^{\mathbb{Z}_\infty}]\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_\infty^+$ which takes $\mathfrak{p}$ to ${_\hat0}\uparrow_\mathfrak{p}$, the largest nonzero term in its support.